# where is the background-color value?

Tags: background-color, inspect-element

I was checking this page code source: https://products.office.com/en-US/mobile/office-iphone

and I could not find the background-color settings in the "Explore Office across devices" section of the page.

There are no colors settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the parent elements, keep going up until you find the top one for that visual part of the page, it has background-color:#f5f5f5; Lot's of the inner elements have transparent background on top of the parent which is solid.

Comment: Yes I found it, Don't know how I missed it! Thanks Elliot!

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped it would be nice if you accepted it as the answer to your question :)